# samba failed to start after install

Tags: samba

I'm trying to get samba running on my box but fail to do so. 
after installing samba i always recieve an errormessage, some libs are missing.

my environment:

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.5 (stretch)
Release:    9.5
Codename:   stretch

Linux test 4.9.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.110-3+deb9u4 (2018-08-21) x86_64 GNU/Linux


● smbd.service - Samba SMB Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/smbd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-09-10 09:07:55 CEST; 12ms ago
     Docs: man:smbd(8)
           man:samba(7)
           man:smb.conf(5)
  Process: 45717 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/smbd $SMBDOPTIONS (code=exited, status=127)
 Main PID: 45717 (code=exited, status=127)

Sep 10 09:07:55 test systemd[1]: Starting Samba SMB Daemon...
Sep 10 09:07:55 test smbd[45717]: /usr/sbin/smbd: error while loading shared libraries: libwinbind-client.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such fi… or directory
Sep 10 09:07:55 test systemd[1]: smbd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
Sep 10 09:07:55 test systemd[1]: Failed to start Samba SMB Daemon.
Sep 10 09:07:55 test systemd[1]: smbd.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 10 09:07:55 test systemd[1]: smbd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
dpkg: error processing package samba (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-11+deb9u3) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (232-25+deb9u4) ...
Processing triggers for ufw (0.35-4) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
```

i tried to resolve this issue doing:

```
apt-get autoremove --purge
apt-get autoclean
apt-get remove samba samba-common
apt-get autoclean 
apt-get autoremove --purge
```

the lib seems to be in the package libwbclient-dev, so i installed libwbclient-dev

```
libwbclient-dev is already the newest version (2:4.5.12+dfsg-2+deb9u3)
```

no success at all.

Comment: Your system was damaged sometime. Try fix with `apt install --reinstall libwbclient0`

Comment: @IporSircer thank you, the message libwinbind-client.so.0: cannot open shared object file is gone, but samba still fail to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an installation when some of the dependencies are missing. Typically it's because you forgot to run `apt-get update` before the `apt-get install...`, and so the expected set of packages doesn't match reality anymore.

Fix

```
apt-get update     # Get the current set of packages
apt-get install    # Complete the installation attempt
```

Comment: seems to fixed the issue with installing. thank you. only one thing. when the service starts at boottime, it fails with a core dump. when starting manually after that, the service comes up and runs